# mysql5.6 does not change character_set values to utf8mb4 with my.ini configuration running on windows and iis

Tags: php, mysql, iis, server

I'm changing the my.ini file on windows, the one who is in C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6, but it only change the values for some character_sets, if you see below when I run `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` in phpmyadmin it shows utf8 for some of the options.

```
**Variable_name**           **Value**
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        utf8mb4
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8_general_ci
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server            utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I already tried several configurations like:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
no-beep

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
#init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
#init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

and different combinations of the options above, but nothing.
Always shows the same values when seeing on mysql.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from MySQL’s utf8 to utf8mb4

**Step 1: Create a backup**

Create a backup of all the databases on the server you want to upgrade. Safety first!

**Step 2: Upgrade the MySQL server**

Upgrade the MySQL server to v5.5.3+, or ask your server administrator to do it for you.

**Step 3: Modify databases, tables, and columns**

Change the character set and collation properties of the databases, tables, and columns to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.

```
# For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each column:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# (Don’t blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on the column type, maximum length, and other properties. The above line is just an example for a `VARCHAR` column.)
```

Since utf8mb4 is fully backwards compatible with utf8, no mojibake or other forms of data loss should occur. (But you have a backup, right?)

Comment: I already did that, my problem seems to be on mysql configuration file

Comment: remove the parameter you have set before but make sure you back up your .cnf file first. Then remove restart mysql.in my case it works.

Comment: remove the parameter, what parameter?

Comment: that you have setup before like all character set related configuration ..Remove it from .my.cnf & then do what i have given in answer.

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 your response is from here, and there says to change my.ini